# Monosodium Diphosphate (NaH3P2O7) Preparation

Tags: salt, process-chemistry

I looked on wikipedia for an answer but I couldn't even find a page for this salt, a subsequent google search didn't further enlighten me.

Does any one know how monosodium diphosphate can be prepared?

Comment: The famous Holleman's book says that the pyrophosphoric acid $\ce{H4P2O7}$  makes only two salts with alcaline elements, and it is, with sodium : $\ce{Na2H2P2O7}$ and $\ce{Na4P2O7}$. It is due to the fact that the two first values of $p$K$_a$ are nearly equal. So, apparently, the monosodium salt $\ce{NaH3P2O7}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you Maurice. So it only coexists in solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{NaH3P2O7}$ is an intermediate acid-salt formed during the neutralization of pyrophosphoric acid ($\ce{H4P2O7}$) which becomes unstable as pH rises and leads to formation of trisodium diphosphate, $\ce{Na3HP2O7}$:

$$\ce{H4P2O7 + NaOH ->[pH < 3] NaH3P2O7 + H2O}$$
$$\ce{NaH3P2O7 + NaOH ->[pH = 3-9] Na2H2P2O7 + H2O}$$
$$\ce{Na2H2P2O7 + NaOH ->[pH > 9] Na3HP2O7 + H2O}$$

This acid-salt can also be produced by the reaction of trisodium phosphate and pyrophosphoric acid:

$$\ce{Na3PO4 + H4P2O7 -> NaH3P2O7 + Na2HPO4}$$

**Notes and references:**

1. Study of crystallization processes in some rare earth vanadate, tungstate and phosphate systems under hydrothermal conditions, K Byrappa and B Nirmala, Indian J. Phyx. 73A (5), 621-632 (**1999**) ([PDF](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/158963013.pdf))
2. [Its CAS number is 13847-74-0](https://www.heraproject.com/files/13-F-04-%20HERA%20STPP%20full%20web%20wd.pdf)
3. [The first dissociation of pyrophosphoric acid](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB0740227.htm) gives the anion, $\ce{H3P2O7^-}$. The dissociation constant is pretty large compared to 2nd, 3rd, and 4th dissociation of the acid.

$$\ce{H4P2O7 + H2O <=> H3O+ + H3P2O7¯ ~~~~ K_{a1} \sim 10^{–1}}$$